# How to install LDAP server and add a user?

Tags: ldap, openldap

I need to test that our application can connect to more than one LDAP servers. We have one working one (running on OSX server). I need to setup another one.

- We tried to set LDAP server on SuSE using Yast. I can connect but I don't know how to add new user.
- I tried to set up LDAP server on my OSX. LDAP is installed by default. But I didn't manage to connect to this server.

All I need is running LDAP server where I can add users.

Existing setting for our application are

```
ldap1.domain = "mrserver.edumate";
ldap1.basedn = "dc=mrserver,dc=edumate";
ldap1.ldap_host = "10.0.0.10";
ldap1.ldap_attribute = "uid";
```

I can install the LDAP server on Windows, SuSE, linux, OSX (not the server as we have only one server)

Comment: If you downvote please say why.

Answer (score 4):

> I can connect but I don't know how to add new user.

Are you familiar with schema, objectclass, and attribute?

E.g.,:

A base.ldif:

```
dn: dc=domain,dc=com
dc: domain
objectClass: top
objectClass: domain
```

An organization unit:

```
dn: ou=it,dc=domain,dc=com
ou: it
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
```

A user:

```
dn: cn=radek,ou=it,dc=domain,dc=com
cn: radek
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
mail: radek@domain.com
...
userPassword: {SSHA}abc
```

The `userPassword` value can be generated by using `slappasswd` utility:

```
$ slappasswd 
New password: 
Re-enter new password: 
{SSHA}p7pvonyVFAHbVB2ux+exlkl3PhLa29SO
```

and using `ldapadd` to add it to OpenLDAP:

```
ldapadd -x -W -D "cn=Manager,dc=domain,dc=com" -f file.ldif
```

Comment: I tried two OSX LDAP browers/editor but none let me add new user... How can I do the password thing?

Comment: I'm not an OSX guy but which browsers did you try? I'm using phpldapadmin, lam (ldap admin manager), ... on Linux.

Comment: I tried `Gawor_ldapbrowser_282` and `LDAPManager`. Does one of your browser come with GUI?

Comment: Sure, they are PHP web-based.

Comment: Try Apache Directory Studio sometime.

Comment: when I run ldapadd I am asked for LDAP password. Whatever password I provide I get `ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)`. Where can I set up LDAP password?

Comment: Or can I set LDAP server so it won't require any password at all?

Comment: Did you set the `rootpw` in `slapd.conf` file? What does it look like?

Comment: How do I restart slapd? `/etc/init.d/ldap start
Starting ldap-serverstartproc:  exit status of parent of /usr/lib/openldap/slapd: 1
`

Comment: Append the output of `sh -x /etc/init.d/ldap start` (or paste it into pastebin) to your original question.

Comment: No `*lap*` nor `*lap*` process was running. `/etc/init.d/ldap start` was issues under root account before posting my comment.

Comment: log from `sh -x /etc/init.d/ldap start` : http://pastebin.com/7pAWFQiz

Comment: Does `/usr/lib/openldap/slapd` exist? How did you install OpenLDAP?

Comment: I set up LDAP server using YaST2. `/usr/lib/openldap/slapd` exist

Comment: `ldap_add: Invalid syntax (21)`